# Occasional background image glitch

Tags: html, css

Every now and then, the background image on my website appears randomly on the sides of the page as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJZ6Y.png

It may happen to you too, but if it does, a refresh clears it: http://centralsirescoop.com/proven-sires/harrison/

The couple of lines of code regarding the background (found in body) is as follows:

```
background-color: #c8dbfb;

background-image: url(images/clouds.jpg), url(images/grass.jpg);

background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;

background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 100%;
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
Browsing on Window 7, Chrome browser v28

EDIT2:
Error does not seem to occur in Internet Explorer 10

Comment: Have you been able to repeat this error in several browsers? What browser are you currently using? What OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some rendering issues with Chrome that I know of, and have experienced multiple times myself. Surprisingly, my searches have not revealed much info on this... But it is definitely there. Even on my Linux system, as well as Windows system.

Try in Firefox and Opera too if you can. I suspect it is Chrome.